# Git URL Issues for SSH

Tags: git

I have justed installed openSSH and I am having trouble with the server URL for SSH. When open a bash - I can login successfully as

> ssh username@some.ip.address

In this directory I have /Git - which is the folder storing my repository - however when I try

> ssh user@some.ip.address:/Git

I get

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname some.ip.address:/Git: no address associated with the name

When I login via just ssh username@some.ip.address - then execute "ls" - I can see "Git" as a directory.

How do I actually get the proper "Arbitrary URL" in Git correct - i.e. I assumed it was

> ssh://user@some.ip.address:/Git

? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ssh into directory. What are you trying to accomplish? You can use "ssh url" `user@host:/directory` with git, but you can't ssh there.

```
git remote add onhost user@host:Git
git fetch onhost
```

One more thing you can do with this url is feed it to `sftp`:

```
sftp user@host:Git
```

Comment: hi :) well yeah i am just try to access a directory i guess initially. at the moment i am just in bash trying to get to git - even when i type ssh user@host:/Git - i get "Could not resolve hostname some.ip.address:/Git: no address associated with the name"

Comment: Like I said, it's not supposed to work as ssh endpoint. It is fine to use it as a git url, though.

Comment: ah ok cool :) so i guess its supposed to generate this error and not login and take to me to the directory (which i thought it should do) ?

Comment: Yes, it's expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

When you log-in using ssh you are usually left in your home directory `/home/bob`.  This means that `ls` will show `Git` if it is in your home directory.  The address in your example assumes `Git` is in the root of the filesystem, which seems unlikely.

Try this address:

```
user@some.ip.address:~/Git
```

---

These addresses are not ssh syntax even though they use the ssh protocol – they are closer to scp syntax.  If you can successfully run

```
scp -r user@some.ip.address:~/Git .
```

then everything should work (note that this may take a while because it copies your whole repository!).

---

You can drop the `ssh://` prefix in your address – `user@some.ip.address:/Git` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (error message) being reported - I found the solution, maybe it will help others in the future:

I upgraded TortoiseGit and that's what caused the issue. We use plink to SSH to our Gitolite server - Tortoise had reverted to ssh.exe

Settings -> Network -> SSH Client